# jinja2 UndefinedError:No caller defined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Recently I have written something using jinja2 and I am a beginner.I encounter some problems when I try to write some html using jinja2.
codes shows like this:

```
{% macro input2(users) -%}
    <ul>
    {%- for user in users %}
      <li><p>{{ caller(user) }}</p></li>
    {%- endfor %}
    </ul>
{%- endmacro %}
{% call(user) input2(users) %}
    user
{% endcall %}
```

And When I use {{ input2(users) }} to call the macro input2,it tells me that

```
 <li><p>{{ caller(user) }}</p></li>

UndefinedError:No caller defined.
```

I want to know why?
Many thanks.

Comment: run your app in debug mode app.run(debug=True) to help provide more details

Comment: where is `caller` defined?

Comment: Have you defined your *caller* globally in templates?

Comment: yeah,
{% call(user) input2(users) %}
    user
{% endcall %}
I think it's the caller definition block,isn't it?Or I get sth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have your macro define with a use of caller().
This implies you can call input2 only with a call.

```
{%- call(u) input2(['a', 'b']) -%}
    {{ u }}
{%- endcall -%}
```

'{%-' and '-%}' are important to eliminate the whitespace of the call in the output

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li><p>a</p></li>
>   <li><p>b</p></li>
> </ul>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to if you use at the end of porgramm macro, method call automatically use macro: input2(users). but if you use macro at the end give Error 'No caller defined'. Look at the photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjNH9.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not share images to your code. Instead, write the code in your answer in a code block. For guidance on how to do that, see [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).